# Not able to execute testng.xml file from gradle command line

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, testng, appium

I have created a gradle project with kotlin in android studio for mobile automation And created task in build.gradle While I am executing test from command prompt eg: 'gradle Test' my test is not getting executed(Message is getting printed which is mention on this tasks). When I am executing directly from testng.xml file than scripts is getting executed successfully.

Below sample code for build.gradle 
`App -> build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appium.automation"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28`enter code here`
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
dependencies {

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'io.appium:java-client:7.0.0'
implementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.12.2'
implementation 'org.testng:testng:6.14.3'
implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.0-M1'
implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:4.3.1'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
implementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-testng:4.3.1'
implementation 'io.cucumber:gherkin:5.1.0'
implementation 'com.aventstack:extentreports:4.0.9'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
print("Hi")
useTestNG(){
    println("Hi2")
    suites '/app/testng.xml'
    println("Hi3")
}
}
```

Project -> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is with test options, try inserting this code to build.gradle in app level.

```java
android {
   testOptions {
          unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
          unitTests.all {
              useJUnitPlatform()
              reports {
                  junitXml.enabled = true
                  html.enabled = false
              }
              testLogging {
                  events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
  
                  // to run JUnit 3/4 tests:
                  testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
                  testRuntime("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.0")
              }
          }
      }
}
```

This issue was mentioned at: https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/622

Answer (score -1):

To execute a concrete test from command line, you can try:

```
./gradlew test --tests "com.MyTestCkass.myTest"
```